# Populating a Javascript array using MYSQL and JSP

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp, d3.js

I'm trying to receive data from a MySQL database using a .jsp, put that data into an array, and then send that array to javascript and use the array to populate a graph made through d3.js. I've done some research on how to do the .jsp part, but it doesn't really make much sense to me. I've found little, if anything, about going from java to javascript as well. This is what I currently have:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>D3 Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%

    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rst=null;
    Statement stmt=null;

    try{
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/usermaster?    user=root&password=7rubA5Ra";

        int i=1;
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
stmt=con.createStatement();
rst=stmt.executeQuery("select * from test ");

%>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var dataset = [ 7, 12, 15, 21, 23, 27, 24, 20, 17, 15,
            12, 14, 17, 22, 20, 19, 18, 20, 25, 27 ];
        var w = 500;
        var h = 100;
        var barPadding = 1;
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);
        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rect1")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / dataset.length);
                })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - d*4;
            })
            .attr("width", w/ dataset.length - barPadding)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d * 4;
            })
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
            });

        /*svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset2)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("id", "rect2")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / dataset2.length);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - d*4;
            })
            .attr("width", w/ dataset2.length - barPadding)
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d * 4;
            })
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                return "rgb(0, 100, " + (d * 10) + ")";
            });*/

        svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) { 
                return d;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return i * (w / dataset.length) + 5;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) { 
                return h - (d * 4) + 15;
            })
            .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "11px")
            .attr("fill", "white");
    </script>
</body>
```

I really just need some one to point me in the right direction. I want the information from the database to be put into the variable dataset.

Thanks,
EmptyBox

Comment: Do you use this password in more than one place? :)

Comment: @Andreas It's a randomly generated password that I use for development/stuff I don't need to keep to myself

Answer (score 1):

Add the JSP tags around where you want to embed it into the JavaScript.

```
 var dataset = [ 
    <% while (rst!=null && rst.next()) { %>
       <%=rst.getInt("<column name>")%>, 
    <% } %>
    ];
```

Comment: Is there something I need to import to use those statements? I get a 'method is undefined for type ResultSet for both of those statements.

Comment: Sorry, I was just using pseudo-code for the ResultSet code.  The right functions are:  while (rst != null && rst.next())  and rst.getInt("<your column name>")

Comment: Oh, haha! Thanks. I'm really struggling with this. I should be able to get it working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do in your case is to **JSON Library.**

*First:* in a **JSP** page retrieve all data from database through ResultSet.
*Second:* keep those in an **JsonArray** and send the array to another page.

*Finally:* Receive the JsonArray in a JavaScript function and use the elements to populate
anywhere in the page.